# How to resize an entry in GTK+

Tags: c++, resize, gtk

I can't resize any entry bar in the GTK horizontal box.  I don't know where the error is in the hbox or in the entry that won't allow me to resize it.

I used this `gtk_widget_size_request` function but it's not working.
This is why I think the hbox is the reason.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;

    GtkWidget *TreeView;
    GtkWidget *title;

    GtkWidget *hbox1;
    GtkWidget *entry1;
    GtkWidget *entry2;
    GtkWidget *entry3;

    GtkWidget *hbox2;
    GtkWidget *btn1;
    GtkWidget *btn2;

    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"hellow world");
    g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,500,690);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);

    TreeView= gtk_tree_view_new();

    entry1= gtk_entry_new(); //this is the entry
    entry2= gtk_entry_new();
    entry3= gtk_entry_new();

    btn1= gtk_button_new_with_label("add");
    btn2= gtk_button_new_with_label("remove");

    hbox1= gtk_hbox_new(0, 3); //this is the hbox
    hbox2= gtk_hbox_new(0, 3);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry1, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry2, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry3, FALSE, TRUE, 3);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox2), btn1, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox2), btn2, FALSE, TRUE, 3);

    vbox= gtk_vbox_new(0,3);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), TreeView, 1, 1, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), hbox1,FALSE, TRUE, 3);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), hbox2, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

Comment: You are explicitly asking to not be resizable with both the `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` and `gtk_window_set_resizable()` calls. Remove them both. To set an initial size to a GtkWindow, use `gtk_window_set_default_size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this line:

`gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);`

And this will work. You can also use `gtk_widget_set default_size` instead of what you currently have.

The issue is that setting the window as not resizable and setting a size request contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

As said, first of all, remove `gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);` to allow GtkWindow to resize. Also notice that your window, while resizing, won't be smaller than 500x690 due to the use of `gtk_widget_set_size_request`.

Then, you did not explain if you want all the three entries expanded or just one or which combination. To allow the entries to expand, you need to set the expand flag to `TRUE` instead of `FALSE`. Right now you have:

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry1, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry2, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry3, FALSE, TRUE, 3);
```

If you want all the entries to expand, then set the flag to `TRUE`:

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry1, TRUE, TRUE, 3);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry2, TRUE, TRUE, 3);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), entry3, TRUE, TRUE, 3);
```

If you want only the last one to expand, then leave the first two as `FALSE` and the last one as `TRUE`

From the [Reference API](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-start)

> void gtk_box_pack_start (GtkBox *box,
>                       GtkWidget *child,
>                       gboolean expand,
>                       gboolean fill,
>                       guint padding);
>
> ...
>
> expand
>
> TRUE if the new child is to be given extra space allocated to box .
>   The extra space will be divided evenly between all children that use
>   this option
>
> ...